# Emulate Run Command?

Tags: vbscript

I'm attempting to create a basic Run command emulator using VBScript, or .bat if that would be easier.
I have had no formal education on these languages, but can do very basic functions from looking at forums and web help. I need this code to be able to request user input for the program they want to open (input box function) and actually open the program.
The server I work at has both Run and CMD blocked, but not written scripts.
Any help would be appreciated.
~Jester

Comment: `WScript.Shell.Run` http://ss64.com/vb/run.html

Comment: s = InputBox("Name?") 

for enter value from user

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This runs CMD and captures it's output.

```
Set Inp = WScript.Stdin
Set Outp = Wscript.Stdout
Set cmd = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Exec("cmd")
cmd.stdin.writeline "dir"
wscript.sleep 20000
cmd.stdin.writeline "dir"
cmd.stdin.writeline "exit"
Do While Not cmd.stdout.AtEndOfStream 

    results = cmd.stdout.readall
    If err.number <> 0 then Exit Do
        wscript.echo results
Loop
'wscript.sleep 5000
```

This shows making your own console program. Most menu options don't do anything.

```
Set Arg = WScript.Arguments
set WshShell = createObject("Wscript.Shell")
Set Inp = WScript.Stdin
Set Outp = Wscript.Stdout


Showmenu

Sub ShowHelpMenu
    outp.writeline " -----------------------------------------------------------------------------"
    outp.writeblanklines(1) 
    outp.writeline " Menu"
    outp.writeline " ----"
    outp.writeblanklines(1) 
    outp.writeline "  1 Help              2 HTML Help          3 Version           4 History"
    outp.writeblanklines(1) 
    outp.writeline "  5 Exit"
    outp.writeblanklines(1) 
    outp.write "Filter>"
End Sub

'=============================================
Sub ShowMenu
    Do
        ShowHelpMenu
        Answ=Inp.read(1)
Outp.write Answ
'       Answ=Inp.readline
        If Answ = "1" Then
            ShowGeneralHelp "TEXT"
        Elseif Answ = "2" Then
            ShowGeneralHelp "HTML"
        Elseif Answ = "3" Then
            Version
        Elseif Answ = "4" Then
            History
        Elseif Answ = "5" Then
            Exit Do
        End If
    Loop
End Sub

'=============================================
Sub History
    On Error Resume Next
    WshShell.Run """" & FilterPath & "FilterHistory.txt""" , 1, False
    err.clear
End Sub

'=============================================
Sub Version
    outp.writeblanklines(1) 
    outp.writeline " Version"
    outp.writeline " -------"
    outp.writeblanklines(1) 
    outp.writeline "   Filter Ver 0.6  -  2015  (Public Domain)"
    outp.writeblanklines(1)
    outp.writeline "   by David Candy"
    outp.writeblanklines(1)
End Sub
```

This shows a basic batch.

```
:start
set /p CMDToExec=Enter Command
%CMDToExec%
Goto Start
```